# WP navigation list classes

Tags: menus

I'm using this code to display my menu:

```
<?php 

$menu_args = array(
     'container'       => '', 
     'menu_class'      => '', 
     'menu_id'         => 'main-menu',
     );

wp_nav_menu($menu_args ); 

?>
```

It works totally fine, but I don't know how to get rid of all these classes attached to every li in my menu?

Example:

```
<li id="menu-item-227" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type current-menu-item page_item page-item-77 current_page_item menu-item-227">
```

It's pretty long, isn't it?

I don't need classes and even IDs here at all, since my menu has one already.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `nav_menu_css_class` filter hook to remove the classes:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'my_nav_menu_remove_class' , 10 , 2);
function my_nav_menu_remove_class($classes, $item){
    $my_class = array('menu-item-class');
    return $my_class;
}
```

Comment: +1, that's a nice trick! But still, every li has an ID and in addiction your code doesn't remove "class" at all, just allows me to set one. When $my_class array is empty it still produces "class=" "" :(

Comment: You can always return an empty array rather than an array with an empty string in it. Even easier, you can just do this: `add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , '__return_empty_array');`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you'll have to write your own custom walker to remove those pesky classes and IDs. I can see about writing something out for you (it's on my own to-do list), but this might help you get started: http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output/

Answer (score 0):

`nav_menu_css_class` only works on custom menus, for standard menus you'll also need to apply the function to the `page_css_class` hook as well.

And at the risk of seeming obnoxious, I also have a small plug-in that does exactly what you're talking about:
http://aarontgrogg.com/2011/09/28/wordpress-plug-in-navigation-menu-ids-classes/

It even gives you the ability to pick-and-choose which, if any, of the WP class you want to keep (for example, all the class that reflect the page you're currently viewing can be handy to have for your CSS needs).

Cheers,
Atg